# how sorting works in the following program?

Tags: c++

I want to know in what way the sort() fuction in following program works?

```
struct Triangle
{
    Vertex* vertices[3];
    Vertex normal;
};
struct VertexIndex
{
    float value; 
    Triangle* triangle;
};
struct Vertex{
    float x,y,z;    
};

   std::vector<VertexIndex>by_z;
  cout<<"test\n";
  for(int i=0; i<triangles.size();i++)
    for(char j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        VertexIndex vi={
            triangles[i].vertices[j]->z,
            &triangles[i]
        };
        //cout<<&triangles[i]<<"\n";
        by_z.push_back(vi);
    }
std::sort(by_z.begin(),by_z.end());
```

does the sort fuction sort the contents in by_z in the order of triangles[i].vertices[j]->z or in the order of triangles[i]??

Comment: what kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: What is `VertexIndex`?

Comment: `VertexIndex` would need a comparison operator for '<' for this to work. So it depends on how that function sorts them.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) requires that either it is passed a function/functor that meets the requirements of [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) or that the type implement an `operator<`. Therefore somewhere in that code must exist (at least for there to not be a compiler error)

```
bool operator<(const VertexIndex& lhs, const VertexIndex& rhs)
{
    //comparison logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easy:
Whatever
`bool operator<(const VertexIndex&a,const VertexIndex&b);`
or
`bool VertexIndex::operator<(const VertexIndex&other) const;`
compares will be the criterion.